# A list comprehension returns wrong result

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've been searching all over but wasn't able to fig this thing out.

I'm from a Java background, if that helps, trying to learn python.

```
a = [
    (i,j,k) for (i,j,k) in [
        (i,j,k) for i  in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0}
                    for j in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0}
                            for k in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0}  if  (i+j+k > 0 & (i!=0 & j!=0 & k!=0))
        ]
]
```

Statement is : get all the tuples whose sum is zero, but none of them should have 0 in it.

Always, this results consists of all tuples. :(

Comment: What's the reason for the outer comprehension? It doesn't actually do anything useful, but you must have had a reason for writing it.

Comment: True, first time i tried without it.. But it still didn't work.. hence I saw if it works with it..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator. You want [boolean `and`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations); [`&` is a *bitwise* operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations):

```
[(i,j,k) for (i,j,k) in [(i,j,k) for i  in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0} for j in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0} for k in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0}  if  (i+j+k > 0 and (i!=0 and j!=0 and k!=0)) ]  ]
```

You can eliminate that nested list comprehension, it is redundant:

```
[(i,j,k) for i  in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0} for j in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0} for k in {-4,-2,1,2,5,0}  if  (i+j+k > 0 and (i!=0 and j!=0 and k!=0))]
```

Next, use the [`itertools.product()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate all combinations instead of nested loops, and [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to test if all values are non-zero:

```
from itertools import product
[t for t in product({-4,-2,1,2,5,0}, repeat=3) if sum(t) > 0 and all(t)]
```

but you may as well omit the `0` from the set and save yourself the `all()` test:

```
from itertools import product
[t for t in product({-4,-2,1,2,5}, repeat=3) if sum(t) > 0]
```

and perhaps you wanted to correct that test to *equals* to 0:

```
from itertools import product
[t for t in product({-4,-2,1,2,5}, repeat=3) if sum(t) == 0]
```

Result:

```
>>> [t for t in product({-4,-2,1,2,5}, repeat=3) if sum(t) == 0]
[(1, 1, -2), (1, -2, 1), (2, 2, -4), (2, -4, 2), (-4, 2, 2), (-2, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you, I did try to use && but now I know i should've used and

Answer (score 9):

In python, `&` is a bit operator. For your need, you should use `and`.

Comment: Besides, the different precedence is a big problem here.

Answer (score 3):

As others already said, you use the wrong operator.

That wouldn't be a problem per se, as you only combine (or, rather, try to combine) boolean values.

But the `&` and the `and` operator have different [precedence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

```
(i+j+k > 0 and (i!=0 and j!=0 and k!=0))
```

would be right, as `and` has a higher precedence than `>` and `!=`.

However,

```
(i+j+k > 0 & (i!=0 & j!=0 & k!=0))
```

turns out to be

```
(i+j+k > (0 & (i != (0 & j) != (0 & k) !=0)))
```

which makes the right hand evaluate to `0`, and the expression `i + j + k > 0` seems to be true for nearly all your data.

Comment: Thanks to you for taking time to explain this difference.

Answer (score 1):

The other guys are addressing the wrong problem. <strike>Yes, `and` is logical and and `&` is bitwise and, but since the operands are booleans, it happens to not actually affect your code.</strike> Whoops; that actually does affect your code, since the precedence is different. Besides that, though, you have a typo:

```
i+j+k > 0
```

should be

```
i + j + k == 0
```

if you want the tuples whose sum is 0.

Comment: Yea, Thank you for your help Changed it - My question was actually around the operators..

Answer (score 1):

Using itertools.product and sum():

```
from itertools import product

list1 = (-4,-2,1,2,5,0)
list2 = (-4,-2,1,2,5,0)

print [ couple for couple in product(list1, list2) if not sum(couple) ]
```

Comment: Was not fast enough, can can use repeat argument of itertools.product as shown by @Martijn